# How do I declare a field to be an identity in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

For example, the column ID. I want it to start at 1, and then increment by 1 for each row.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table TableName
(
    ID int identity(1, 1) primary key
)
```

The `identity(1, 1)` is what's important here. The first argument represents the seed (meaning initial) value, the second argument represents the increment rate. This means that the first record will have a value of `1`, and each subsequent record will increment this value by `1`.

Had we specified, for example, `(7, 2)`, the first record would have a value of `7`, then each record would increment by `2` (so `7`, `9`, `11`, and so on).

Note that obviously the `primary key` part is not required, but the identity column in a table (if it has one) is usually the primary key. If it isn't in your case, then just remove that portion.

Answer (score 1):

set column to identity column

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_DataTable  
(  
  id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
  col1 varchar(50)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL 2005/2008:

Under Column Properties for your column, expand "Identity Specification", then change "IsIdentity" to true.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically or manually?

In SQL Server - right-click the table, select modify, click on the column, under "Identity Specification" set "Is Identity" to true and leave the increment and seed each at 1.

(If you meant programmatically... a couple of people already answered as I was typing :) )